# content-length or size of the same js files are different across servers

Tags: javascript, iis, bundle, content-length

So I deployed a development project to a dev server from my local host today, and I've done a considerable amount of optimizations. I shrunk the size of the content, sped up rendering time, and everything looks great. I published the code to the dev server, and I went on chrome to test everything out, went on the networking tab on the debugging tools to see whats going on, and disabled cache on both servers.

localhost: IIS 10.0 
dev machine: IIS 8.5

Here are the results:

DOMContentLoaded are both around the same: ~1.5 seconds 
Load are both around the same: ~1.7 seconds

But here's where things get weird:

localhost: 722KB transferred 
dev mach: 1.4MB transferred

Code on both machine are the same. All javascript files are bundled and minified. So I decided to check out at least one of the files; my bundled and minified jquery file:

localhost: 38.6KB 
dev mach: 84.4KB

why is this so different? I copied both text into a notepad, and used beyond compare program to test the text on both files, and they are the same! I looked at the file description of both saved files, and both equal 84KB. If that's the case, why is chrome telling me the file size of this incoming file is 38.6KB? How could they both be loaded and rendered at the same time if the ratio of the data sent are a difference of 1:2 ?

I now tested this on IE11

localhost: 383.84KB 
dev mach: 1.63MB

and my bundled and minified jquery file on IE11:

localhost: 38.6KB 
dev mach: 84.4KB

I'm wondering if this has something to do with IIS? web.configs are practically the same on both ends. Or if localhost is doing less than what IIS has to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the **Static** and **Dynamic** Compression options of **IIS** on both machines.

When Dynamic Compression is enabled on **IIS**, it by default uses **GZip** compression while transferring files/pages. And this compresses/reduces the size of the files/pages.

Comment: Wow! I didn't have this feature installed on IIS on my dev server and neither on production, and when I enabled it, it compressed everything the way I have it on my localhost. What an incredible answer. Also IIS mentions this: "Use of dynamic compression may increase processor utilization and may reduce the overall performance of the server" Is this recommended to enable?

Comment: Personally I recommend using it. GZip is way too great when enabled. you can test the performance of your website using (https://gtmetrix.com/) you will see that it recommends using GZip.